# Using Stripe with multiple e-commerce clients

Tags: java, e-commerce, stripe-payments

We have a Java-based system that provides websites for clients, which includes e-commerce. We will use Stripe for charging but I am unsure of the best setup for all of our clients. Each client has their own website and that website will have multiple customers purchasing products through it.

Should we set up a Stripe account for each of our clients so that we use a different API KEY for each site or is it better to have a single Stripe account under our own company's name and set up multiple clients within that account?

I can't find anything in the Stripe docs for handling standalone clients who each have multiple customers but I'm assuming that a site like Shopify would use this kind of setup.

Comment: Have you looked into Stripe Connect: https://stripe.com/docs/connect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this would be with Stripe Connect as koopajah mentioned.

Your clients would make their own Stripe account and then they would connect to your system through OAuth. This would give you a set of keys that you would use as your publishable key and secret key as well as allow you to charge an application fee if wanted.